# Why isn't the style showing (colors, font,etc..) when I link my stylesheet to w3.css?

Tags: html, css

I have linked the w3.css stylesheet in my html (as suggested at w3schools) to utilize their responsive template but it doesn't appear to be working. I have linked it as such within the head tag of my html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="w3-theme-brown.css">
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Please paste your code or a link to a working demo.

Comment: I've removed the brackets. Does that help you see the html I've used?

Comment: first and foremost, i would like to see your directory hierarchy, where you've placed the CSS, and HTML files, and then some snippets of code, more specifically the <head> tag code part. Then we can try to help you.

Comment: do you have them in the same folder as your html file?

Comment: @B.Garbs You **should** have gone through how to post code in the question. See your updated one. Make sure you have both the CSS and HTML file on the same directory.

Comment: @B.Garbs Friendly advice. W3Schools is the worst resource. You should either use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/) or [Web Platform Docs](https://docs.webplatform.org/).

Comment: I guess it's obvious that this is my first question on stackoverflow. Thanks for all the advice on utilizing this page. I'll look into how to post code here. Also, I'm an aspiring developer and just getting started so thanks for your patience as I figure this all out

Comment: Flagged for `unnecessary downvotes to answers without clarifying the issue`.

Comment: I think I figured it out -- not having the css file in the same folder, easy fix. -- @PraveenKumar, thanks for the advice on MDN or Web Platform. I will certainly check those out. Any other advice or help for someone getting started would be greatly appreciated! Many thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your CSS code is in your .css file, and your HTML and CSS files are in the same directory if you are using `<link href="File.css" rel="stylesheet">` and not writing the directory.
Also, don't forget to put your `link` tags between opening and closing `head` tags.

Comment: I have flagged the main question for "unnecessary downvotes to answers without clarifying the issue" and +1 this.

Answer (score 0):

It should look like the example I posted below.

If it's still not loading then it would to do with the location of your stylesheets(css).

Example - `href="path/to/stylesheet"`

The path would start from the current directory your HTML is in... so if you had `index.html` in the root directory and your css files a sub-directory then the example would look like this.

Example - `href="css/w3.css"`

Example - `href="css/w3-theme-brown.css"`

//HTML

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="w3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="w3-theme-brown.css">
</head>
```

Comment: I have flagged the main question for "unnecessary downvotes to answers without clarifying the issue" and +1 this.